# How create a list of IP,port in python/bash?

Tags: python, bash

i work as security consultant and I'm trying to improve our work methods.
I want to write a script that takes an input such as:

`11.22.33.44
55.66.77.88`

and turns it into:

`11.22.33.44,80
11.22.33.44,443
55.66.77.88,80
55.66.77.88,443`

in input of a list of IPs (one per line), and the output is each IP TWICE, once with port 80 and once with port 443, separated by a comma

i tried working with bash and python (limited knowledge) but im not sure where to start, any help, even a link which will point me in the right direction will be much appreciated.

disclaimer: 
I apologize for not showing what i attempted, im terrible at any type of programing and i searched for a long while, for many things, but wasn't sure what and how to look (so it was a huge waste of time)

Comment: do you mean just concatenating strings?

Comment: you have tried anything???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script should do the trick.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read LINE
do
  echo "$LINE,80"
  echo "$LINE,443"
done
```

That having been said, generally speaking a higher standard of research is expected than was demonstrated with this question. So, please, next time, show us what you've tried first.

Comment: first of all, thank you. Even though im not new to security, any kind of programing isn't my strong suite (working on it), honestly, i looked for a long time in Google, but wasn't even sure what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

And a Python version, in case that's helpful:

```
import sys

for addr in sys.stdin:
    addr = addr[:-1]  # remove trailing newline
    print '{},80'.format(addr)
    print '{},443'.format(addr)
```

Comment: very helpful! thank you! how do i apply this to a source file?

Answer (score 1):

using python:

```
my_ip = raw_input("Enter IP: ")
while my_ip:
    print "{},80\n{},443".format(my_ip, my_ip)
    my_ip = raw_input(Enter IP: ")
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
 sed 's/\(^.*$\)/\1,80\n\1,443/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, Awk is missing.

```
awk '{ print $0 ",80"; print $0 ",443" }' file
```